# What does connflag=FALSE mean?

Tags: python, aws-iot, paho

I’m using a script to connect a raspberry to AWS `IOT`.
It contains a reference `connflag`. I couldn’t find any explaination for so far.

```
 import paho.mqtt.client as paho
 import random
 import string
 import json
 from time import sleep

 connflag = False
```

Does it belong to the `paho-Mqtt` module and if so what does it? Is there a reference?

Comment: Is it used anywhere else in the code?

Comment: As shown it means no more than `connflag` being set to `False`.

Comment: Perhaps this can give you a clue https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/501

Comment: Sure it’s used all over the script. I’m just looking for some documentation what it does or what it stands for. I mean the term “CONNFLAG”

Comment: What "flag" variables like that usually do is to store program state. Given the name here I'd expect it to indicate whether or not a connection is open, or something like that. Typically, such flags are internal to the code and not meant to be relevant to the end user or an external programmer, so I'm wondering a bit why you need to know what it means.

Comment: Mmh, as a programmer you should always know what is in your code. There cannot be unknown parts, that’s at least my understanding and that’s why I’m looking for an explanation.

Comment: I don't believe a programmer can possibly know what is in the code, considering the amount of dependencies that are present in any modern program. Totally second Antimon: if you don't need it, you don't need to understand it either. Anyways, where this flag is used? Please add some examples of a function or two in the library which use this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By googling, I guess it's this code (or a derivative)? https://github.com/mariocannistra/python-paho-mqtt-for-aws-iot/blob/master/awsiotpub.py

You can see that it's doing

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global connflag
    connflag = True
    print("Connection returned result: " + str(rc) )

# ...

if connflag == True:
    tempreading = uniform(20.0,25.0)
    mqttc.publish("temperature", tempreading, qos=1)
```

That is, `connflag` gets set when the client connects to the MQTT queue, and no readings are published before it's connected.

The name for the variable itself could be better (e.g. `is_connected` would probably make immediate sense).